# How to make the final value of a countdown become new starting value?

Tags: php, datetime, countdown

I am working on a school project where I am keeping track of a user's tweeting frequency per week. I have working code, but at the end of each 1-week period, I need to manually adjust the new starting tweet total and the date of one week in the future.

How can I automate it so the final tweet count becomes the new starting tweet count, and one week gets added to the ending date? Am I heading in the right direction with the code below, or should I be storing these final tweet total values in a database? Thank you!

```
// Get current tweet total and calculate current count

$ptTotal = $ptObject->{'statuses_count'};
$ptStart = 572;
$ptCount = ($ptTotal-$ptStart);

// Set end date & convert to EST

$ptdatestr="2017-05-30 12:00:00";
$ptdate=strtotime($ptdatestr)+14400;

// Calculate time remaining

$ptdiff=$ptdate-time();
$ptdays=floor($ptdiff/86400);
$pthours=round(($ptdiff-$ptdays*86400)/3600);

// Re-set start value and add one week to countdown

if ($ptdiff <= 0) {
$ptStart = $ptTotal;
$ptdate = $ptDate + 604800; 
}
```

Comment: I see two options here. On every request, calculate the number of weeks since the initial date and update it. Another way would be to use a CRON job (every week or so) to call some PHP script that restarts the counting and dates (although this last option is more a UNIX feature rather than a web server one). Check https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job about how to set up a CRON job. Of course, if you want to keep data, you would need to use a database management engine or so (MySQL or similar). You could also use plain files, but that's up to you really.

Comment: @mickmackusa even if it "feels" like an answer, the truth is I'm not answering it correctly: it just points to some research for the OP. I'm not, for example, answering how to add that specific week that he needs to his count (that's part of the question). So I felt like a comment would be more appropiate. The question also feels incomplete (what have he tried? I don't know...), so the same idea: a comment is probably appropiate since it doesn't answer all the parts of the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I say regardless of how you are automating this code block (see Alejandro's comment), you should move away from using any approach that includes `+86400` (or a factor of).  Things will go BONK in the night when daylight savings is involved.

Instead, I recommend that you integrate [DateTime objects](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php).  They are highly versatile and have specific features that will aid you in your specific project.  This is a full list of related functions: http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Implementing Datetime objects and functions will make your project solid and lean.  Immerse yourself in the above php manual pages and the comments that follow; and continue to research on StackOverflow.

More to your specific questions: Yes, I think you are on the right path.  Yes, I think I'd store the data in a database.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you Mick I will look into the DateTime features